# Creating Gson object in JSP

Tags: json, jsp, gson

I'd like to create a Gson object to pass over request to a servlet, from a JSP page (a simple form). I'd like to do that without using scriplets. So, supose the following page:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
            <form action="SomeServlet">
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="ID">Dog ID</label> 
                    <input type="text" name="ID" id="ID"/> 
                    <label for="dogName">Dog Name</label> 
                    <input type="text" name="dogName" id="dogName"/>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm able to use JSTL, expression language, JavaScript and jquery, but I'm not wanting to use scriptlets, in order to improve ellegance and gain readability. How should I do that? Thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 0):

There's something called JSON-taglib which allows you to put JSON out from a JSP.  But it sounds like you want to do the reverse (i.e. send JSON back to the Servlet).

In that case, I think doing that with a combination of technologies which you list might be really difficult.  I'm thinking the only way to do this would be to write your own tag using the SimpleTag API in the JSP/Servlet spec.